# Delete multiple values from mySQL database at once

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I've been working a bit on basic mySQL-database stuff, and have learned to show the contents, insert, delete, and update data, all via PHP.

Now I've been tasked with putting it all together in one page, where I can select multiple persons (my database contains names) and delete them at once, instead of typing each name individually.

This is the file I use to show the contents of my database:

```
include'databaseinfo.php';
include'databaseconnectioncheck.php';

$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, fornavn, efternavn, lokation FROM $table1_db");
echo "Der er ". $result->num_rows ." personer i databasen <br><br>";

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
    echo "ID " . $row['id'] ." er " . $row['fornavn'] . " " . $row['efternavn'] . " som bor i " . $row['lokation'] . ".<br><hr>";
```

And this is the file I use to delete element from my database:`
    Fornavn: 
    
    Efternavn: 
    
    Lokation:

```
if (!empty($_POST['fornavnFraFormDelete']) AND ($_POST['efternavnFraFormDelete']) AND ($_POST['lokationFraFormDelete'])) {

include 'databaseconnectioncheck';

$fornavnFraFormDelete = $_POST['fornavnFraFormDelete']; //Variablerne oprettes fra formfeltet
$efternavnFraFormDelete = $_POST['efternavnFraFormDelete'];
$lokationFraFormDelete = $_POST['lokationFraFormDelete'];

$conn->query("DELETE FROM $table1_db WHERE fornavn='$fornavnFraFormDelete' 
    AND efternavn='$efternavnFraFormDelete' AND lokation='$lokationFraFormDelete'");
    echo "Du har fjernet ".$fornavnFraFormDelete. " " .$efternavnFraFormDelete." fra databasen.<br><br>";            
}

if (isset($_POST['fjernalt'])) {

include 'databaseconnectioncheck';

$conn->query("DELETE FROM $table1_db");
    echo "<br> <br> Du har fjernet alle fra databasen.";
}
```

I hope you understand it, even though some of it is in Danish, if not then tell me, and I'll translate it.

Anyways, I've made a picture, that should explain how I'd like it to be, and again if it doesn't, let me know. 
[image]

Comment: Look at DELETE from TABLE WHERE conditions

Comment: Please close this question. You offer money, that is something that nobody want to see here. we do it for free. but we ony helping here,NOT writing code for you.

Comment: Add checkboxes where the value is the person's ID. Look for checkboxes on submit. Use these checkboxes to put data into `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (...)`. Have fun.

Comment: Since you are a littel into PHP i give this hint: you can do `DELETE FROM xyz WHERE id in(1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: You are also open to `SQL injection`

Comment: I know, we've had quite a few students do this to prank each other. I'm using localhost though, so it shouldn't be a problem :-)

Comment: @aynber How would i go about that? This was my original thought, I just can't get the checkboxes to work :/

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I've tried, but can't seem to get it working, and I'm getting desperate now (1,5 hours till deadline). Any chance you could give me another hint? :)

Comment: @ChrisBint I see what you mean, but how do i make it add the checkboxes in front of every name, so i can choose them? :)

Answer (score 0):

First on your check boxes have name `name="id[]"` in this manner.

You have checkbox like this for id i assume

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="1">
                                ^ give this parentheses after name to all checkboxes of id.
```

After that you need to use foreach for this

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $value) {
   $conn->query("DELETE FROM $table1_db WHERE id = $value);
    echo "Du har fjernet ".$fornavnFraFormDelete. " " .$efternavnFraFormDelete." fra databasen.<br><br>";            
   }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? :)